# jqPlot, canvasrenderer labels with html inside them

Tags: jquery, jqplot

i am using jqplot  to graph some data. my axis label has a micro in it. `&micro;`
but it is being passed through as that and not an entity.
here is the code

```
axes:{
    yaxis:{
        label:'L,&micro;H',
        autoscale: true,
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
    }
}
```

is there a way to not have the entity be converted?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your actual problem is, but you could try replacing

```
label:'L,&micro;H',
```

with

```
label:'L,&amp;micro;H',
```

I don't really understand what you are saying

---

Huh...? Could you be more clear on what your real problem is???

Test site with `&micro;` and `&amp;micro;` http://jsbin.com/olove

[jqplot http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7264/clipboard01pm.jpg](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/7264/clipboard01pm.jpg)

Which one do you want? Both versions work first one displays the character `Μι` itself second one displays the html entity.

Comment: no that just passes through directly as it is. the problem is javascript doesnt recognize entities. it translates them so you dont get the character just the code...

Comment: Check expanded answer. Really unclear what your problem is. Please be more clear. And if you mean that javascript e.g reports `"L,&micro;H".length == 10` instead of `"L,&micro;H".length == 4` remember that javascript isn't a html parser. To javascript this is just a normal string. Only when displayed the browser will convert the entity in the string to the actual character represented by the html-entity